# Weird and inconsistent Model issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I feel like I'm missing something rather important in both circumstances, but I can't seem to figure either out:

1) I have a model named TestCase -

```
class TestCase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test_suite
  scope :queued, lambda { where("test_cases.suite_id IS NOT NULL") }
  scope :assigned_to, lambda { |sid| where(:suite_id => sid) }
end
```

The controller can interact with it perfectly fine. When trying to display information from it in either the view or via the view helper such as `TestCase.all`, I get a `NoMethodError (undefined method 'all')`  If I call it with `::TestCase.all`, that works. I had a theory that it has something to do with the fact that it's associated to another model (belongs_to ...), I just can't find anything to confirm that or tell me why that happens.

2) On another project I have yet another model named Artwork. Again, it has associations (belongs_to). In this case, I can access it just fine in the view, and all the methods within it work fine for the controller except if I try to do dynamic method calls. In this case I have a simple toggle for -

```
@artwork = Artwork.find(params[:id])
value = params[:value].to_sym
@artwork.update_attributes(value => !@artwork.method(value).call)
```

That gives me a `NoMethodError`. However, if I add - `if @artwork.respond_to?(value)`  - then it works as expected. Again, I can't figure out why.

Both items I get working using the mentioned methods, but again, I feel like I'm really missing something important here.

Comment: Fix your code by indenting it 4 spaces please. Code that is hard to read means you get less answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: problem 1 -- Don't call your model "TestCase". That conflicts with the Rails `TestCase` class.

Re: problem 2 -- That's an odd way of doing things. You might get it working by using

```
@artwork.send(value)
```

but keep in mind that a rogue user could pass in any method name through the form and wreak havoc.

Comment: As for the first problem, yeah, I'm blind. Thanks for pointing that out. The second one... I was told that it was because the accessor methods aren't built until first invoked (because they hit method missing.) Running call it doesn't hit that, hence it doesn't work. As for rogue users... good point. Thanks!